# Weird i2cdetect output

Tags: i2c

I want to connect the Geekworm X728 to my PI4. It is a UPS for the PI4 that allows to read AC state and battery state and power down / up the pi when power gets lost / comes back. As addition it has an integrated RTC. It is a HAT that that normally goes on top of the PI but because I use a bigger cooler for the Pi, I put in below it and connect it using jumper cables.

More information on

[Wiki](https://wiki.geekworm.com/X728)

[Hardware](https://wiki.geekworm.com/X728-hardware)

[Software](https://github.com/geekworm-com/x728/blob/master/x728-v2.1.sh) (contains several short programs, easy to understand from the vendor)

When running i2cdetect it shows weird output.

In my first test I only connected 5v, GND and I2C to the PI to power it up and read from i2c.

I triple-checked the wiring. (Numbers are pins)
3.3v and GND (1, 9) is connected to a 5v fan so it is silent.
3 and 5 are connected to 3 and 5 for i2c for the X728.
2, 4, 6 and 14 are connected to 2, 4, 6 and 14 for Power between X728. I wired them twice because I wasn't sure about the wire width and I have an USB SSD connected.

The Pi is running debian, not raspian.

Linux pi4 5.10.0-0.bpo.9-arm64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.70-1~bpo10+1 (2021-10-10) aarch64 GNU/Linux

Because there are significant differences between the two OSes and I would modify the vendor software anyways, I later want to write my own control program in Rust.

My config.txt

```
arm_64bit=1

core_freq=
enable_uart=1
upstream_kernel=1

# *** Display ***
disable_overscan=1

# *** I2C ***
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
dtparam=i2c1=on
dtoverlay=i2c1,pins_2_3

# *** RTC ***
dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,ds1307
```

Now when running `i2cdetect -y 1` (or -y 0) the output looks weird.

```
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f
10: 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 1a 1b 1c 1d 1e 1f
20: 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 2a 2b 2c 2d 2e 2f
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 38 39 3a 3b 3c 3d 3e 3f
40: 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 4a 4b 4c 4d 4e 4f
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 6a 6b 6c 6d 6e 6f
70: 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77
```

It does not look like SDA is grounded (I'd expect ALL of the above to return a number, dome don't as you can see) but it is still strange. I would expect it to show 2 up to a handful of devices at max. At least 68 should show the RTC and there should be the controller where I can read the battery state from.

No matter if I reboot or run the command several times.

I don't have any experience with i2c so I'd like to ask. What causes this output? Could it be that there is a frequency problem?

Take a look [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXVVF.jpg) for a photo of the wiring.

I had a fan hat connected before (last year some time) that worked but was noisy, bad and didn't provide proper cooling at all but it was connected using i2c to set fan speed.

The pi isn't overheading when connected. I read that this could be caused by accidently burning it.

Thanks for any advice.

If there is any further information you need please kindly ask.

Comment: It's a wiring problem.  Either SDA or SCL or being pulled to ground.  Need a clear photo if you want help.  Does the i2cdetect report quickly or is there a noticeable delay after each address?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I checked the wiring again using a multimeter from board to board. Every cable I plugged is connected as I would expect and none does respond to ground except for ground, same for 5v. I also checked if the slightly moved GPIO on top of the X728 is the same for the pins which is. Please see [this](https://imgur.com/Zuzxpne) for a photo of the wiring. When reading there is no delay and i get `Error: Read failed`.

Comment: the error is from i2cget, both i2cget and i2cdetect return fast without any noticable delay

Comment: (1) Is your wiring 4 meters long? (2) Are you overloading the bus with 12 devices? If yes, remove all on board pullups. (Rpi I2C onboard has a strong 1k8 already) (3) Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62757687/raspberry-pi-4-i2c-bus-not-working-correctly/62786449#62786449, (4) Talk is cheap, show me the photo. :)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback but I'd like you to re-read my comments. You'll find a picture linked which answers most of your questions. (1) about 15cm, the shelf-available jumper cables. (2) The Pi and The X728 are professionally manufactured and sold, i just connect them together. I'd assume more people would have problems if its a manufacturing issue but maybe one of both is bad. (3) see answers before and (4) Talk is cheap, reading is more expensive. I couldn't resist, don't be mad :-). You most likely just missed that there is a link in my comment above. Does this help you help me?

Comment: Your question is not as clear as it should be, and we've no idea how a X728 is supposed to be connected. You should use the schematic tool, and show the connections in a diagram to clear this up. Otherwise, I'd begin troubleshooting by getting one thing to work first (the RTC perhaps), and then add something else.

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback. Of course I can provide more information. I updated the question and placed more information and direct references the the product, specs and simple to understand, short software and hope this helps.